# How can I make Spring-MVC output HTML

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How can I make Spring-MVC output HTML. Right now I have Spring-MVC filling in data in a List like the one below:

```
 <ul>
     <li><c:out value="${memberrequest.name}"/></li>
     <li><c:out value="${memberrequest.title}"/></li>
     <li>District: <c:out value="${memberrequest.district}"/></li>
     <li><c:out value="${memberrequest.school}"/></li>
     <li><c:out value="${memberrequest.requestor}"/></li>
 </ul>
```

the out put looks like:

[image]

But if the data is blank like title, school etc I don't want a line to blank so I was thinking that I could creating this list in the spring code and then pass the html back to the JSP page but it looks like Spring will not let you do it

Comment: Some options: In your controller, check if a value is empty/null, putting a default if it is. In jsp, use a `<c:if>` to check if a value is empty/null and use a default if it is. Use `thymeleaf` instead of `jsp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning HTML from your controller defeats the very idea of MVC, because your controller takes over the responsibility of the view.

Instead, use the `<c:if>` tag within your JSP. More information here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL4.html#wp74001 (note: the first paragraph of this explanation seems to indicate that you should use a scriptlet; it really doesn't, and if you read down you'll see the JSTL approach).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this you can use the `escapeXml="false"` attribute on `c:out` like so:

```
<c:out value="${myHtmlString}" escapeXml="false"/>
```

But as parsifal says, it's best to construct your HTML in your view if you can.